# Wallet Connect integration to dapp with react for signer

Tags: reactjs, solidity, ethers.js, decentralized-applications, wallet-connect

I created a straightforward decentralized application (DApp) using Ether.js and integrated it with WalletConnect.
The UI was done with reactjs.
The Ether.js library is functioning correctly and successfully connects and executes transactions through MetaMask. I also correctly installed and implemented WalletConnect. However, when I click the "connect" button, it successfully initiates the connection, but when I attempt to execute transactions using Ether.js, it doesn't utilize the WalletConnect connection as expected.

I attempted to use reactjs on a UI to integrate WalletConnect into a basic DApp with the expectation that it would utilize the established WalletConnect connection for transactions.
However, the DApp continued to rely on Ether.js, which was functioning perfectly.
This issue becomes problematic when using a mobile phone browser, as it lacks the necessary wallet extensions. Consequently, I'm in search of guidance on how to seamlessly integrate WalletConnect with the existing Ether.js connection.

I'm eager to learn how to effectively implement WalletConnect into my DApp. Are there any tutorials available that provide step-by-step instructions for achieving this?